# How can I enhance javascript function that iterate callback?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading 'Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja' and I found a task to enhance a function that iterate callback.

This is the task.
"enhance the function so that the page author can also pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the callback in addition to the iteration index."

```
    function forEach( list, callback ){
        for( var n=0; n < list.length; n++ ){
            callback.call( list[n], n );
        }
    }

    var list = ['shuriken','katana','nunchucks'];

    forEach(
        list, 
        function(index){ console.log(index); console.log(this) }
    )
```

Comment: How (and why) is the author supposed to pass these arguments?

Answer (score 0):

User can pass any number of arguments to the callback. you can simply use arguments parameter to read them.

eg.

```
...list ,function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```